# VueJS - for role X show page Y only

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have multiple user types in `VueJS` project. Any role (except role X) starts with `/streamers` as a home page.

I want role X not to be able to see `/streamers` page. I want them to see `/streamers/<CURRENT_USER_ID>/detail` page ONLY.

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'Home',
    component: Dashboard,
    redirect: '/streamers/',
    children:[
      {
        path: 'streamers/',
        name: 'Streamers',
        component: Streamers,
      },
      {
        path: 'streamers/:id/detail/',
        name: 'StreamerDetail',
        component: StreamerDetail,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    path: '/login',
    name: 'Login',
    component: Login,
  }
]
```

How can I do that? The `Dashboard` component needs to load the current user using API. Then it should check if the user has role X (`$store.state.auth.user.is_X`). If yes, they should be able to see their detail page only.

**Dashboard**

```
<template>
   <div if="$store.getters.isAuthenticated">
....
   </div>
</template>

export default {
  name: "Dashboard.vue",
  data() {
    return {
      snackbar: {
        color: null,
        message: null,
      }
    }
  },
  mounted(){
    this.$store.dispatch('checkCookiesOnInit') // checks for JWT token in cookies
    if (!this.$store.getters.isAuthenticated){
      this.$store.dispatch('refreshToken')
    }
  },
  methods: {

  },
}
```

Comment: Create a `getter`,  to check if `user === x`

Answer (score 0):

You could use `router.beforeEach` to create a route guard with these rules.

**Example:**
https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-cartwright-yhcuy?file=/src/main.js

```
import { createApp } from "vue";
import { createRouter, createWebHashHistory } from "vue-router";
import App from "./App.vue";
import Home from "./components/Home.vue";
import View1 from "./components/View1.vue";
import View2 from "./components/View2.vue";

const getLoggedInUser = () => {
  // user to test routes with
  const user123 = {
    name: "John",
    id: "123",
    role: "user"
  };

  const user5 = {
    name: "Sam",
    id: "5",
    role: "user"
  };

  const admin = {
    name: "Dean",
    id: "5",
    role: "admin"
  };

  return user123;
};

const routeGuard = (to, from) => {
  const { loggedInRequired, idCheckRequired, authorize } = to.meta;

  // if login not required then allow entry
  if (!loggedInRequired) {
    return true;
  }

  const currentUser = getLoggedInUser();

  if (!currentUser) {
    // not logged in so redirect to home
    return false;
  }

  if (authorize.length && !authorize.includes(currentUser.role)) {
    // if they don't have the correct role redirect home
    return false;
  }

  if (idCheckRequired && to.params.id != currentUser.id) {
    // if the :id param doesn't match the logged in user's id
    return false;
  }

  return true;
};

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHashHistory(),
  routes: [
    {
      path: "/",
      name: "Home",
      component: Home,
      children: [
        {
          path: "streamers/",
          name: "Streamers",
          component: View1,
          meta: {
            loggedInRequired: true,
            authorize: ["admin"],
            idCheckRequired: false
          }
        },
        {
          path: "streamers/:id/detail/",
          name: "StreamerDetail",
          component: View2,
          meta: {
            loggedInRequired: true,
            authorize: ["user"],
            idCheckRequired: true
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
});

router.beforeEach(routeGuard);

createApp(App).use(router).mount("#app");
```